# Are there any possibilities to restrict other developers from installing new npm packages in the project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, yarnpkg

We have few developers working on a project and we would like only the leads to install the `npm` packages. We don't want people to randomly add `npm` packages.

Now, we can restrict the `master` or `develop` branch and review the PRs for changes in `package.json` before merging. But, we would like to automate the process and would like the install to fail if someone who doesn't have access tries to install a new package.

I know that there is a way to restrict package access but, that won't be helpful for us. So, is it possible to configure `npm` in a way where we could pass the access details and `npm` would only allow the developers who have access to install packages?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking at this because you've already progressed beyond the "trust your employees" stage - ie have you had the "please don't add NPM packages without discussion" conversation yet?

Comment: An idea can be to use git hooks to check for changes before committing code. But, it doesn't makes sense to allow partial team members to add packages. This doesn't looks like a team at all. It would be better to educate the beginners and groom them.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes, I did and I understand your point. But, I thought if there is a solution out there then why not use it rather than relying on human intervention. Recently, one of the devs added a package to solve a problem and things started breaking. It took us a while to debug as the dev was on vacation and we couldn't reach him. We informed everyone again but now we are a bit paranoid about it.

Comment: @Fawaz That would restrict all the developers from adding the package unless you are aware of a working solution. I am using `husky` for managing `git-hooks`

Comment: Proxy requests to npm, whitelist allowed modules, give access to modify the whitelist to the trusted ones.

Comment: @AlexBlex This seems like a solution. I'll try and update here. Can you please add it as an answer so that I can accept it if it works?

Comment: It is a hint, not an answer. If it works and you can share enough details to post a proper answer, please do it.

Comment: @AlexBlex Sure.